Clustering fails for larger distances on Maps on SwiftUI
I am trying to apply clustering on my app. I have, say 90 listings, and i want to combine these when the zoomLevel is 60 and above and make them separate below 60( This might not be a good practice! If you know a better approach let me know). In my screenshots, as you can see, between NY and NM there is a huge distance and the annotations don't come together and are not shown as 1. But between Mallorca and Barcelona they are successfully coming together. What do i miss in this code?


I tried to add a dynamic zoom level text at the top to see what happens. I also want to show the total number of listings on the pins when they come together. I could not achieve that as well.
class MapViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var annotations: [MKPointAnnotation] = []

    func createAnnotations(from listings: [PetSittingListing], zoomLevel: Double) {
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        var temporaryAnnotations: [MKPointAnnotation] = []

        for listing in listings {
            group.enter()
            if let latitude = listing.latitude, let longitude = listing.longitude {
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.title = listing.title
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                temporaryAnnotations.append(annotation)
                group.leave()
            } else if let locationName = listing.location {
                let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
                searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = locationName
                
                let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
                search.start { response, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error searching for location: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        group.leave()
                        return
                    }
                    
                    if let coordinate = response?.mapItems.first?.placemark.coordinate {
                        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                        annotation.title = listing.title
                        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
                        temporaryAnnotations.append(annotation)
                    }
                    group.leave()
                }
            } else {
                group.leave()
            }
        }

        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            if zoomLevel > 60 {
                       self.annotations = self.clusterAnnotations(annotations: temporaryAnnotations, zoomLevel: zoomLevel)
                   } else {
                       self.annotations = temporaryAnnotations
                   }
               }
         }
    
    
    private func clusterAnnotations(annotations: [MKPointAnnotation], zoomLevel: Double) -> [MKPointAnnotation] {
        var clusteredAnnotations: [MKPointAnnotation] = []
        
        let clusterRadius = log(zoomLevel) * 5
        
        for annotation in annotations {
            if let existingCluster = clusteredAnnotations.first(where: { existing in
                let distance = haversineDistance(from: existing.coordinate, to: annotation.coordinate)
                print("Distance between annotations: \(distance) km")
                return distance < clusterRadius
            }) {
                existingCluster.title = "\(Int(existingCluster.title ?? "1")! + 1) Listings"
            } else {
                clusteredAnnotations.append(annotation)
            }
        }
        return clusteredAnnotations
    }
    
    private func haversineDistance(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Double {
        let earthRadius = 6371.0 // Kilometre cinsinden Dünya yarıçapı
        let dLat = (to.latitude - from.latitude).degreesToRadians
        let dLon = (to.longitude - from.longitude).degreesToRadians
        
        let a = sin(dLat / 2) * sin(dLat / 2) +
                cos(from.latitude.degreesToRadians) * cos(to.latitude.degreesToRadians) *
                sin(dLon / 2) * sin(dLon / 2)
        
        let c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
        return earthRadius * c
    }
}

extension Double {
    var degreesToRadians: Double { self * .pi / 180.0 }
}



You can always cluster manually if you don’t like the standard

what does this mean?

It means the API is not going to cluster these annotations. If you want them clustered, you need to write custom code to show one annotation for whatever annotations you want clustered.

But i wrap MKMapView for SwiftUI here. They adviced me on here to follow that way. And it should work no?

It means that if you don’t like the way Apple clusters annotations you have to create your own clustering code. Their code doesn’t offer a ton of customizations.
